# Die Hard detonator insertion -- "F*** it"

Tags: plot-explanation, die-hard

Just before John McClane tosses the C-4 plastic explosive down the elevator shaft in *Die Hard*, he is inserting detonators into the C-4. After inserting two detonators, he says "Fuck it" and inserts a third.

What did he mean by "Fuck it"? Was there something different about the way he inserted the third detonator, or what?

Comment: overkill is underrated so to speak. He was definitely annoyed and really wanted to lay the hurt on the two dudes downstair.s

Comment: And one might also ask... *what was his plan there, anyway?!* How on earth did he know where it'll hit and who it'll hurt?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the way he says it suggests that two detonators is plenty for the task at hand, but he is annoyed enough to want to be really, really sure, so he inserts the third detonator as well.

Comment: This was my interpretation as well. There's also the aspect of "what the hell am I going to use the detonators for after this", making it pointless to save them. On the other hand, throwing your explosives down an elevator shaft without having them actually explode is rather embarrassing, so might as well use all you can.